# How to create a random graph in networkx from an existing graph?

Tags: python, networkx

I want to generate a random graph using the edge distribution from the original graph.
Is there a way in networkx module to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean same degree distribution.

The command `nx.configuration_model(degree_list)` will do it.

So in your case, given an existing graph `G`:

```
H = nx.configuration_model([G.degree(node) for node in G])
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, is there any way I could fit it to a particular distribution?
Say, if I wanted to fit it to a hypergeometric distribution.

Comment: As in the degree distribution be from a particular distribution?  Yes - you generate a degree list using whatever distribution.

Comment: It would be great if you could probably add a code snippet on how to do that? I am just getting started with networkx. Cheers~

Comment: Instead of `[G.degree(node) for node in G]` in the argument for `nx.configuration_model`, you'll need to create a list, say `L` whose entries come from whatever distribution you want.  Depending on what that distribution is, you would need to generate `L`.  Then you just use `nx.configuration_model(L)`